# How to loop over a range of numbers or use seq with a for loop in bash?

Tags: bash

I am using for loops in bash to loop over an array of IPs from file. There are around 38 IPs and in one file and I want to select any range of IP like for example I should be able to loop over if a user asks to go for IP address from range 10 to 20. But with the for loop I am not able to find out how to use **seq** or give a range. Below is an example:

```
mapfile -t ip < SippIPs.txt
echo
read -p 'How many Sipp's are required: ' choice
echo

for ((j=1; j<=$choice; j++)); do
        sipps=${j[@]}
        ips=(${ip[sipps-1]})
        echo "$sipps"
        echo "$ipList"

        echo "    ----  Launching SIPp $sipps ----  "
        sshpass -p "root12" ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$ips <<EOF1
        screen -S sipp -d -m bash -c 'cd /usr/local/src/sipp-3.3; ulimit -Hn 65535; ulimit -Sn 65535; ./sipp -i $ips -mi $ips -sf HA_demo.xml -inf HA_demo.csv 10.171.0.231:5060 -p 5060 -r 1 -rp 1s -l 1 -m 1 -watchdog_minor_threshold 1500 -watchdog_major_threshold 4000 -watchdog_major_maxtriggers 30 -trace_err -aa -d 350s -oocsn ooc_default -t u1 -trace_screen -skip_rlimit && exec bash'
        exit
EOF1
done
```

Below is how my ips text file looks like:

```
[root@megahost23 MasterScript]# cat SippIPs.txt
10.171.0.201
10.171.0.202
10.171.0.203
10.171.0.204
10.171.0.205
10.171.0.206
10.171.0.207
10.171.0.208
10.171.0.209
10.171.0.210
10.171.0.211
10.171.0.212
10.171.0.213
10.171.0.214
10.171.0.215
```

Can someone guide please how can I give a range with the abovementioned for loop I am using?

Comment: I don't understand `sipps=${j[@]}`. `$j` is a number, not an array.

Comment: Just storing it in a variable. The code is working fine.

Comment: It's already in a variable `j`

Comment: Where does the user specify the range of IPs they want? You just asked for a number, not a range.

Comment: You can't have `'` inside a single-quoted string.

Comment: For example if I want to loop between 10 to 20, how would I be able to do that?

Comment: `for ((j = 10; j <= 20; j++))`

Comment: More generally, `for ((j = $start; j <= $end; j++))`

Comment: No the user inputs the range and the IPs are in the file and the index starts from 1. For example the user is first asked what range you start from and the user types 20 and then they are asked where does it end and they type the response. How can I implement the following?

Comment: `read -p 'Start from' start; read -p 'End at' end` then use the above loop.

Comment: Then use `$ip[j-1]` in the loop.

Comment: Okay got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$ read -p 'min: ' min
min: 3

$ read -p 'max: ' max
max: 10

$ mapfile -t zumba < /tmp/range
$ for (( i=min-1; i <= max-1 ; i++ )) ; do echo ${zumba[i]}; done
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```